# VSIX Extension uses 3rd party DLLs unable to load one of the dependency

Tags: visual-studio-2012, dll, visual-studio-extensions, vsx, vsix

I am developing an extension to VS2013. Since it will be installed through MSI, I am changing the base directory to installation folder using **ProvideBindingPath** attribute to package class. But the 3rd party dll reference which will be loaded in runtime is not picking dll from the probed path. Its always looking into Visual studio **devenv.exe** folder. Is there any way to force the dll to look into my installation folder.

```
using MD=Microsoft.VisualStudio.Modeling.Shell;

MD.ProvideBindingPath(SubPath = @"")]
public sealed class AutomationCommandPanePackage : Package
    { 

     public AutomationCommandPanePackage()        
     {

        string installationPath = HelperMethods.GetInstallationPath();

        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(HelperMethods.GetInstallationPath())) return;

        // Change default config file at runtime.
        using (AutomationConfigurationManager.Change(installationPath, "AutomationPro.config"))
        {
            // Trace.WriteLine(string.Format(CultureInfo.CurrentCulture, "Entering constructor for: {0}", this.ToString()));
        }            

        Assembly a = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
        Type type = a.GetType("AutomationCommandPanePackage", true);
        System.Reflection.MemberInfo info = type;
        var attributes = info.GetCustomAttributes(true);

        foreach (var attrib in attributes)
        {
            if (attrib is MD.ProvideBindingPathAttribute)
            {
                ((MD.ProvideBindingPathAttribute)attrib).SubPath = installationPath;
                break;
            }
        }
```

Comment: Has the `ProvideBindingPath` attribute been moved to another namespace; in VS2012 and before this type was located in `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell`. I would try to not initialize the `SubPath` property. And: assembly metadata is readonly; I would say that setting the `SubPath` property on reflected attributes does not have any effect...

Comment: Matze, ProvideBindingPath  attribute did not move to any other namespace and it is from modeling class. [link] (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.modeling.shell.providebindingpathattribute(v=vs.120).aspx) It was working fine with VS2010. issue started when i migrated the code to 2013. the same piece of code is not working.

Comment: I resolved issue using LoadLibrary() from System.Runtime.InteropServices; 
since my dll to be loaded is COM iterop.

     public static class win32
    {

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName);

        [DllImport("kernel32.dll")]
        public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);

    }

in package.cs i wrote this

    win32.LoadLibrary(Path.Combine(installationPath, "apidsp_windows.dll"));

Comment: There are two attribute classes having the same name, but the intended use is different. The attribute class that would solve the problem is declared within the `Microsoft.VisualStudio.Shell` namespace. See: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.visualstudio.shell.providebindingpathattribute.aspx

Answer (score 2):

I have been able to successfully load third party (telerik) assemblies in my extension using below code.

Register to `AssemblyResolve` event in your Package class constructor

```
AppDomain.CurrentDomain.AssemblyResolve += OnAssemblyResolve;
```

Then in handler load packages as below:

```
string path = Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Location;
path = Path.GetDirectoryName(path);

if (args.Name.ToLower().Contains("telerik.windows.controls.gridview"))
{
       path = Path.Combine(path, "telerik.windows.controls.gridview.dll");
       Assembly ret = Assembly.LoadFrom(path);
       return ret;
}
```

I have not had any issues with the above approach.

Comment: Thanks, Utkarsh, In my case dlls wont be available in execution path. MSI will put them in installation folder.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved issue using 
`LoadLibrary()` from

```
System.Runtime.InteropServices;
```

since my dll to be loaded is a COM iterop dll.

```
public static class win32 
{ 
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
public static extern IntPtr LoadLibrary(string dllToLoad); 
[DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
public static extern IntPtr GetProcAddress(IntPtr hModule, string procedureName); [DllImport("kernel32.dll")] 
public static extern bool FreeLibrary(IntPtr hModule);
}
```

in package.cs I loaded assembly like this

```
win32.LoadLibrary(Path.Combine(installationPath, "apidsp_windows.dll"));
```

Comment: Where did you put the code above (`[DLLImport(...`) ?