# Deploy 3rd party dll files with VSIX Visual Studio extension

Tags: dll, visual-studio-extensions, vsix, mahapps.metro

I am developing a Visual Studio Extension. I have used a 3rd party dll for UI controls. It adds 2 dll files as reference. But when I deploy my Visual Studio extension, the dlls does not seem to get copied. How do I deal with this scenario and deploy the dll from 3rd party package along with VSIX installer ?

On investigation, I found out that the dlls are getting copied properly inside "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions" folder, but somehow the extension is unable to load them.

Comment: This has already been answered, check out this [SO Post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20001191/vsix-extension-uses-3rd-party-dlls-unable-to-load-one-of-the-dependency)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. The problem was that the assembly was not in the list of references and therefore it was not getting loaded. To load the assembly manually, I used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load() method

Answer (score 1):

[You need to tell VS where to load the assembly.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/gg590213(v=vs.100).aspx)

Comment: I have resolved the issue. The problem was that the assembly was not in the list of references and therefore it was not getting loaded. To load the assembly manually, I used AppDomain.CurrentDomain.Load() method

Comment: Yes that is right. But for some reason when the assemblies are getting loaded, the 3rd party assembly which I have referenced is not under the list. That is why I have to add it manually.

Comment: Can you share your pkgdef or something when you tried to set the Provide* attributes?